# Closing off a process when complete in Powershell

Tags: powershell, uac

Good afternoon,

I have a script I am running at the moment and in my script there are two lines of code.
The first line installed OneDrive with admin privileges without asking for permission (bypasses UAC).
The second line runs the application.

My problem is when the second line is run it will state the following:

"OneDrive can't be run using full administrator rights - Please restart OneDrive without administrator rights"

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\OneDriveSetup.exe" -ArgumentList “/peruser /childprocess /cusid:$cusid /silent” –wait 
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($newexepath) | Out-Null #$newexepath = "c:\users\test\appdata\local\microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe"
```

Is there a way to stop the process in line one when it is finished, basically telling the script to forget about bypassing UAC?

Comment: Split it to two scripts: one is installing and the second one is running. Run only first one with high-privileges.

Comment: @montonero Not the answer I was looking for but it does work. Ideally would love it in one script but I understand that might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to disable administrative rights temporary by using “net user administrator /active:no” in cmd command. Then, try to relaunch the OneDrive client and see whether it helps. If so, you can reactive administrative rights by using “net user administrator /active:yes” in cmd command. It should help on this issue in OneDrive.

In addition, I also found that the problem could be caused due to the highest privileges settings in Task Scheduler. You can search Task Scheduler from Start and click “Task Scheduler Library”. Then find OneDrive in the list and double click on it. In the window open, make sure “Run with highest privileges” option is unchecked and click OK to save the setting. After your reboot the computer, the error message should be gone.